# What does MongoDB's documentation mean when it says ObjectIDs are "likely unique"?

Tags: mongodb, unique, primary-key, objectid

**Situation:** The MongoDB documentation for [ObjectIds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) says "ObjectIds are small, **likely unique**, fast to generate, and ordered."

**Question:** Why and how would MongoDB's ObjectIds be merely *likely unique*, rather than fully unique?

**What I've tried:** Googling and doing a cursory search on SO. Some other SO questions seem to refer to the problem of non-uniqueness, but I haven't seen one with a full explanation yet. There are also some Medium articles that may address the point, but Medium is not free after the first few articles.

Comment: You can open it in incognito, although the articles there usually disappoint.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Why and how would MongoDB's ObjectIds be merely likely unique, rather than fully unique?

Two reasons:

1. Each ObjectId is generated locally on the client. The different clients are not coordinating the values they are generating. Therefore it is *possible* that there are two clients that happen to generate the same random numbers and would thus generate exactly the same ObjectIds. Highly unlikely but possible, hence "likely unique" wording.
2. [ObjectId generation algorithm](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/objectid.rst) specifies the use of a 3-byte counter that is used to disambiguate the values generated in the same second. If you generate more than 16 million ObjectIds in the same second, that counter will overflow and the client you are using will start to generate ObjectIds it already generated a moment ago.