# Mongodb always increased "_id" field?

Tags: mongodb, subscription, changestream

Is `_id` field in mongodb always increased for the next inserted document in the collection even if we have multiple shards? So if I have `collection.watch` do I always get higher `_id` field for the next document than for the prev one? I need this to implement catch-up subscription and not to lose any document. So on every processed document from `collection.watch` I store its `_id` and if crash - I can select all documents with `_id` > `last_seen_id` in addition to `collection.watch`.

Or do I have to use some sort of auto-incemented value? I don't wanna cause it will hurt performance a lot and kill reason of sharding.

Answer (score 3):

ObjectIds are guaranteed to be monotonically increasing *most* of the time, but not all of the time. See [What does MongoDB's documentation mean when it says ObjectIDs are "likely unique"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65401210/what-does-mongodbs-documentation-mean-when-it-says-objectids-are-likely-unique/65417740#65417740) and [Can a 4 byte timestamp value in MongoDb ObjectId overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65842129/can-a-4-byte-timestamp-value-in-mongodb-objectid-overflow/65847941#65847941). If you need a guaranteed monotonically increasing counter, you need to implement it yourself.

As you pointed out this isn't a trivial thing to implement in a distributed environment, which is why MongoDB doesn't provide this.

One possible solution:

- Have a dedicated counter collection
- Seed the collection with a document like `{i: 1}`
- Issue find-and-modify operation that uses https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/ and no condition (thus affecting all documents in the collection, i.e. the one and only document which is the counter)
- Request the new document as the update result (e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-crud-operations/#update-options `return_document: :after`)
- Use the returned value as the counter

This doesn't get you a queue. If you want a queue, there are various libraries and systems that provide queues.

Comment: Way back when the official structure of an ObjectID included things like "machine id", some clients (meteor) didn't bother, for whatever reason, and simply set all bytes randomly. Even if we do lead with timestamp, there's clock drift. So yes, "most of the time" is quite accurate, although that's not much of a "guarantee", is it? :)

Comment: When ObjectId isn't increased? I mean, if client doesn't generate `_id` itself, so MongoDB will

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo: when clocks drift apart between shards, for example

Comment: So, what options do I have? I know about optimistic locking, but anything else?

Comment: @DSM about your edit, it won't guaranteed that every document from `collection.watch` will have `counter` greater than last document's `counter`

Comment: I didn't say to use change streams, but if you did, why not?

Comment: I mean, if we use `find-and-modify` to get next counter value, then imagine this situation: client A get counter(1), client B get counter(2), client B insert document, client A insert document. So we will get counter(2) before counter(1) from `collection.watch`. And if we crash right after counter(2), we lose document with counter(1)... Right?

Comment: Cause with this solution we can't guaranteed that we won't skip any counter values. So after 1 can be 5 in some situations.

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo: alternatively, you can make sure your `ntpd` is working on all servers and maybe restart with a leeway (`last_id` - X seconds).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, seems like its most appropriate solution, but we should deal with duplicates somewhere after, but its double at least :)

Comment: Find and modify shouldn't be conditional on the counter value.

Comment: Clock drift is a minor concern. Every time the ObjectId counter  rolls over  the generated values may decrease.

Comment: "shouldn't be conditional"? What do you mean?

Comment: If you want a queue, use a queue. Collections are not queues.

Comment: I want to do persistent event store, not a queue

Comment: I mean something like this - https://gist.github.com/Ryuzaki42/dcc275285ac0e1c90ce79531f233ed97

Comment: You can ask that as a new question, taking care to avoid https://xyproblem.info/.